# Kubernetes multi-cloud Set up

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, on-premises-instances

Is it possible to have Kubernetes master as an on-premise instance and another one on Google for example or is it required for all nodes to be on the same network?

If I understand correctly the only blocking factor one has to take care of is to open the right ports for the master and worker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible, but you should use the vm instances on GCP.

If Kubernetes master as an on-premise instance can communicate the vm instances on GCP, no problem.

But how do you use HA?..
I shouldn't recommend this architecture.

Comment: Thx for the comment. Am using it as a proof-of-concept so HA its not a problem for now.

Comment: Hi, I agree with Dante, this doesn't sound like a good idea. At the very least this isn't a conventional architecture so there won't  be much help available when it inevitably goes wrong.